# How do I refocus the window that a HTML5 notification is created from?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I'm using the following JavaScript to shoot off a notification when the window is not focused.

```
if( document.hidden || document.webkitHidden )
{
    var notification = 
        new Notification( "title", { 
            body: "body" } );
    notification.onclick = function()
    { 
        window.focus(); 
    };
}
```

It works great in Chrome - when I click on the notification, the relevant tab is refocused / windows is brought into focus. In Firefox, it appears that window.focus() does nothing.

Is there a cross-browser (forget about the oddball cousin, IE) solution that allows me to refocus a window when I click on a notification generated by it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for FireFox:

```
var e = document.createEvent('Event');
e.initEvent("focus", true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work for Firefox 25.0.1. Furthermore, the method you've provided is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent